# Ubuntu, JavaFX, A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, jre

I have already asked this question here: [link to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519242/ubuntu-javafx-a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment)

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.02 x64, oracle JDK 1.8.4 and I try to run JavaFX8 project but I get this message in eclipse(not every time however):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f69a19a4f78, pid=7035, tid=140090187572992
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b25) (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6c3f78]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x38
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f699c28a800):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=7057, stack(0x00007f6949cde000,0x00007f6949ddf000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 128 (SI_KERNEL), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f6949dd9b70, RBX=0x00007f6949dd9a80, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x3b746e6576456e6f
RSP=0x00007f6949dd98d0, RBP=0x00007f6949dd9a50, RSI=0x00007f6949dd9ae0, RDI=0x00007f699c28a9f8
R8 =0x00007f699c1e3f28, R9 =0x00007f6949dd9a80, R10=0x0000000000000011, R11=0x00007f698d1fb000
R12=0x00007f699c28a800, R13=0x00007f699c1e3f28, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x00007f699c28a9f8
RIP=0x00007f69a19a4f78, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f6949dd98d0)
0x00007f6949dd98d0:   00007f6949dd9f30 00007f698cdf8768
0x00007f6949dd98e0:   00007f6949dd9930 00007f6949dd99b0
0x00007f6949dd98f0:   00007f6949dd9a80 00007f6949dd9ae0
0x00007f6949dd9900:   00007f699c28a9f8 00007f69a19c4810
0x00007f6949dd9910:   00007f6960011a60 00007f6960011ae0
0x00007f6949dd9920:   00007f6960011e48 00000000000003d8
0x00007f6949dd9930:   00007f69880d4f08 00000000d8954d60
0x00007f6949dd9940:   000000000000006f 000000000000000a
0x00007f6949dd9950:   00000000d8c35188 00007f6900000000
0x00007f6949dd9960:   0000000000000000 00007f6949dd9a20
0x00007f6949dd9970:   00007f699c217040 0000000100000140
0x00007f6949dd9980:   00007f69880d4f08 00007f6949dd9938
0x00007f6949dd9990:   00007f6949dd9979 0000000800000005
0x00007f6949dd99a0:   00007f69880d4f00 00007f699c28a800
0x00007f6949dd99b0:   00007f69a2220590 00007f69a2d03470
0x00007f6949dd99c0:   00000000d8954a78 00007f69880d4f08
0x00007f6949dd99d0:   0000000000000000 00007f699c28a800
0x00007f6949dd99e0:   00007f69880dee68 00007f699c28a800
0x00007f6949dd99f0:   00007f69880dee68 00007f699c28a800
0x00007f6949dd9a00:   00007f6949dd9a50 00007f69880dee68
0x00007f6949dd9a10:   00007f69880dee68 00007f69880dee68
0x00007f6949dd9a20:   00007f699c28a9f8 00007f6949dd9a80
0x00007f6949dd9a30:   00007f699c28a800 00007f6949dd9ac0
0x00007f6949dd9a40:   00007f699c1e3f28 00007f699c28a9f8
0x00007f6949dd9a50:   00007f6949dd9b40 00007f69a19a971f
0x00007f6949dd9a60:   00007f699c28a800 00007f697eedcfc4
0x00007f6949dd9a70:   00007f6949dd9b50 3b746e6576456e6f
0x00007f6949dd9a80:   00007f69a22211f0 00007f69a2d03470
0x00007f6949dd9a90:   000000009c217040 0000000000000063
0x00007f6949dd9aa0:   0000000000000000 0000003000000018
0x00007f6949dd9ab0:   00007f6949dd9c30 00007f6949dd9b70
0x00007f6949dd9ac0:   00007f699c28a800 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f69a19a4f78)
0x00007f69a19a4f58:   00 00 48 85 d2 48 89 bd b0 fe ff ff 48 89 b5 a8
0x00007f69a19a4f68:   fe ff ff 4c 89 8d a0 fe ff ff 0f 84 10 09 00 00
0x00007f69a19a4f78:   4c 8b 22 4d 85 e4 0f 84 04 09 00 00 48 8b 45 10
0x00007f69a19a4f88:   48 8b 98 38 01 00 00 48 83 7b 18 f7 0f 87 06 06 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f6949dd9b70 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f699c28a800
RBX=0x00007f6949dd9a80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f699c28a800
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x3b746e6576456e6f is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f6949dd98d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f699c28a800
RBP=0x00007f6949dd9a50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f699c28a800
RSI=0x00007f6949dd9ae0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f699c28a800
RDI=0x00007f699c28a9f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f699c1e3f28 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f6949dd9a80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f699c28a800
R10=0x0000000000000011 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f698d1fb000 is at entry_point+32 in (nmethod*)0x00007f698d1fae90
R12=0x00007f699c28a800 is a thread
R13=0x00007f699c1e3f28 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f699c28a9f8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f6949cde000,0x00007f6949ddf000],  sp=0x00007f6949dd98d0,  free space=1006k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x6c3f78]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x38
V  [libjvm.so+0x6c871f]  jni_CallVoidMethodV+0x10f
C  [libglass.so+0x1b798]  JNIEnv_::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+0x98
C  [libglass.so+0x19355]  WindowContextBase::process_key(_GdkEventKey*)+0x225
C  [libglass.so+0x22bf0]  WindowContextBase::im_filter_keypress(_GdkEventKey*)+0x1f0
C  [libglass.so+0x254d4]  process_events(_GdkEvent*, void*)+0x204
C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x591ec]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.enterNestedEventLoopImpl()V+0
j  com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._enterNestedEventLoop()Ljava/lang/Object;+15
j  com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop()Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter()Ljava/lang/Object;+42
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+107
j  javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait()V+74
j  javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait()V+11
j  javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait()Ljava/util/Optional;+41
j  classes.LoginDialog.showLoginDialog()V+10
j  controller.MainWindowController.buttAdministratorAction(Ljavafx/event/ActionEvent;)V+22
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100
J 856 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d0ed304 [0x00007f698d0ed200+0x104]
J 855 C1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d0ecd44 [0x00007f698d0ec960+0x3e4]
j  sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+7
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+40
J 856 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d0ed304 [0x00007f698d0ed200+0x104]
J 855 C1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d0ecd44 [0x00007f698d0ec960+0x3e4]
j  sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+20
j  javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;)V+19
j  javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+12
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+51
J 1483 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventType;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (34 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d29fb94 [0x00007f698d29f640+0x554]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+8
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+11
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+29
J 1433 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (101 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d288ec4 [0x00007f698d288d20+0x1a4]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+17
J 1433 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (101 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d288ec4 [0x00007f698d288d20+0x1a4]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+17
J 1433 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (101 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d288ec4 [0x00007f698d288d20+0x1a4]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+10
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+37
j  javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+30
j  javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+86
j  javafx.scene.control.Button.fire()V+15
j  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+23
j  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+83
j  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+5
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+5
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+28
J 1483 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventType;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (34 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d29fb94 [0x00007f698d29f640+0x554]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+8
j  com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+11
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+29
J 1433 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (101 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d288ec4 [0x00007f698d288d20+0x1a4]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+17
J 1433 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (101 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d288ec4 [0x00007f698d288d20+0x1a4]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+17
J 1433 C1 com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event; (101 bytes) @ 0x00007f698d288ec4 [0x00007f698d288d20+0x1a4]
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Ljavafx/event/EventDispatchChain;Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+10
j  com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)Ljavafx/event/Event;+46
j  javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventTarget;Ljavafx/event/Event;)V+30
j  javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;Z)V+491
j  javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Ljavafx/scene/Scene$MouseHandler;Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;Z)V+3
j  javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Ljavafx/scene/input/MouseEvent;)V+6
j  javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Ljavafx/event/EventType;DDDDLjavafx/scene/input/MouseButton;ZZZZZZZZZ)V+46
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+438
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$208.get()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/View;JIIIIIIIZZ)V+103
j  com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(JIIIIIIIZZ)V+30
j  com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(IIIIIIIZZ)V+181
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Z)V+0
j  com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Z)V+7
j  com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$41.run()V+12
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

.. when my application runs this code:

```
ChangeRoot changeRoot = new ChangeRoot(Main.mainStage, CONSTANTS.ROOT_EMPLOYEE_WINDOW.string, "Employee panel", true);
changeRoot.doFadingTransition(borderPane, CONSTANTS.FADE_OUT.value, CONSTANTS.FADE_IN.value);
```

Source code of my program:

```
public class ChangeRoot{
    private boolean bChangeStageSize = true;
    private boolean bFadeStage = true;

    private String sNewTitle;
    private boolean bResizable;
    private Controller controller;
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private FXMLLoader loader;
    private Parent root;

    public ChangeRoot(Stage primaryStage, String sRoot, String sNewTitle, boolean bResizable){
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.bResizable = bResizable;
        this.sNewTitle = sNewTitle;

        loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(sRoot));

        try{
            root = loader.load();
            controller = loader.getController();
        }catch(IOException exception){
            ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("Error while loading fxml file", exception);
            exceptionDialog.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    /**************************** PUBLIC METHODS *******************************/
    public Controller getController(){
        return controller;
    }

    public void doFadingTransition(Pane actualPane, double fadeOutMillis, double fadeInMillis){
        actualPane.setDisable(true);
        //fading out
        final DoubleProperty stageOpacity = Main.mainStage.opacityProperty();
        final DoubleProperty oldPaneOpacity = actualPane.opacityProperty();
        if(bFadeStage == true)
            oldPaneOpacity.bindBidirectional(stageOpacity);


        Timeline fadeOut = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(oldPaneOpacity, 1.0)),
            new KeyFrame(new Duration(fadeOutMillis), e -> {
                    if(bResizable == true)
                        Main.mainStage.setResizable(true);
                    else
                        Main.mainStage.setResizable(false);
                    if(bFadeStage == true)
                        oldPaneOpacity.unbindBidirectional(stageOpacity);
                        changeRootAndWindow();
                        fadeIn(fadeInMillis);
            },
            new KeyValue(oldPaneOpacity, 0.0) 
        ));

        fadeOut.play();
    }

    public final void changeRoot(){
         changeRootAndWindow();
    }

    /**************************** PRIVATE METHODS *******************************/
    private final void changeRootAndWindow(){ //it will do depending what was put to the constructor
        if(primaryStage.isMaximized() == true){
            primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
        }
        primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle(sNewTitle);

        if(bChangeStageSize == true){
            Main.mainStage.setHeight(controller.getMainPane().getPrefHeight() + 38);
            Main.mainStage.setWidth(controller.getMainPane().getPrefWidth() +16);
        }
    }
    private void fadeIn(double fadeInMillis){
        if(controller == null){
            ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("insert controller class", new Exception());
            exceptionDialog.showAndWait();
        }

        final DoubleProperty newPaneOpacity = controller.getMainPane().opacityProperty();

        final DoubleProperty stageOpacity = Main.mainStage.opacityProperty();
        if(bFadeStage == true)
            newPaneOpacity.bindBidirectional(stageOpacity);

        Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(newPaneOpacity, 0.0)),
            new KeyFrame(new Duration(fadeInMillis), actionEvent -> {
               if(bFadeStage == true)
                   newPaneOpacity.unbindBidirectional(stageOpacity);
            },
            new KeyValue(newPaneOpacity, 1.0)
        ));

        fadeIn.play();
    }
}
```

---

It doesn't happen every time but most of it. Usually there is no problem right after I start eclipse and run my program for the first time.

I looked in the internet for the answer and tried this:

```
sudo unlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1
```

and also this:

> I've tried adding the the below line to the end of eclipse.ini, but Eclipse can't start at all:
>
> ```
>   org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
> ```
>
> I think there is some typo error, the line should be:
>
> ```
>   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
> ```
>
> and this worked for me.

but nothing helps.... I don't know what to do.

There is no problem when I run the same code on Windows.

Comment: libsoup doesn't even appear in the stack dump. Cross-posting is frowned upon.